# sparkJobServer - running spark sql

Tags: spark-jobserver

It looks like spark.jobserver.context.SQLContextFactory is deprecated. Could somebody help me with the example on how to run Spark SQL with the latest ( 0.8) version of SparkJobServer.

Thank you.